# How to use windows-latest VMImage for Azure pipeline to build project with Microsoft Office dependencies?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, agent

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline for a visual studio project. The pipeline works when using a self-hosted agent that has the Microsoft office suite installed locally. However, when I use the windows-latest VMImage, it does not work. I get the following error:

Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Is there some way to work around this while still using the windows-latest vmImage as the pool?

Answer (score 0):

> How to use windows-latest VMImage for Azure pipeline to build project with Microsoft Office dependencies?

Please try to install the nuget package [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/) to your projects.

That because this assembly is not available (onto the GAC) onto the Hosted Build Agent.

Note: Do not forget use the Nuget Restore build task before the build task.

Comment: The nuget package was already installed to my project. I also was using nuget restore before the build task. Not sure why I don't have this issue with a self hosted agent but only with the windows one.

Comment: @WesleyBrandt, Have you check if the nuget restore task restore that package and check the path in the project file and the path of the packages?